# UIScrollView is moving up if I hide the NavigationBar and the ToolBar

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, autoresizingmask

I have a problem, I created a zoomable UIImageView with a UIScrollview, everything works perfect, exept the UIImageView is not in the center anymore and every time I hide the Tool- and NavigationBar the UIImageView/UIScrollView is moving up.

I already set the autoresizingMask:

```
scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

but it won't work, can someone please help me?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem with iOS 7, and read I had to set

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

for the view controller, but it did not work for me. After I have released I had to put it in viewDidLoad method of the parent view controller of the view controller.

Comment: What is the parent view controller of the view controller?!

Comment: Really..?? This single line waisted two hours of mine... This is crazy. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Just like @Mert answered, you can either set it in code `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` or you can set this in storyboard, in the scroll view in one of the inspectors you can un-check the checkbox that automatically adjusts the scroll view content.

**EDIT**

The checkbox is in the **attributes inspector** of the `UIScrollView`, it's called **Autoresize Subviews** under drawing section.

Btw, this behaviour only happens in iOs7, because of the transparent `UINavigationBar` thing.

Comment: Thanks @Nour .. A great tip - but I'm not finding that checkbox. PLease, what exactly is it labelled?  Which of the six inspectors is it in?  Thanks a lot.